# SFML Custom Class Not Closing

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a custom class called "Game"

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Text.hpp>
using namespace sf;

Game::Game(float length, float height, std::string title) {
    this->length = length;
    this->height = height;
    this->window = new RenderWindow(VideoMode(this->length, this->height), title);
    this->isOpen = true;
    display();
}

bool Game::pollEvent() {
    return window->pollEvent(e);
}

void Game::close() {
    window->close();
}

void Game::display() {
    window->display();
}

void Game::clear() {
    window->clear(Color::White);
}

void Game::paint(Drawable component) {
    window->draw(component);
}

void Game::sleep(long millis) {
    sf::sleep(milliseconds(millis));
}


Game::~Game() {
}
```

And a main class that executes the program

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Game.h"

using namespace sf;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Game game(1000, 1000, "My Class Works!");
    while (game.isOpen) {
        while (game.pollEvent()) {
            if (game.e.type == Event::Closed) {
                game.close();
            }
        }
        game.clear();
        game.sleep(1000/60);
        game.display();
    }
}
```

The window displays on the screen, however, when I try to close the window, it freezes and does not close. I am new to SFML so I would like to know if I am doing this the correct way, and my class is how it is supposed to be. Everything else seems to work apart from that. Why is it not closing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flag `game.isOpen` stays true, so the while loop continues to excute, but your `RenderWindow` is closed.

Update the `Game::close` method like this :

```
void Game::close() {
    window->close();
    isOpen = false;
}
```